# Astah: Deleting the numeration

Tags: sequence-diagram

I am using `Astah` to create sequece diagram of my system and I would like to delete the number in the front of the method name above the edge such as `2,2.1,2.1.1, 2.1.1.1, 2.1.1.1.1, 2.1.1.1.2, 2.1.1.1.3, 2.1.1.1.4`: How can I get it?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You are able to hide the Sequence number. Please refer to the post below.
http://astah.net/support/questions/111

Comment: Link connects to general Astah site. Please give an answer on SO, not a link; a link may always die.